# Increasing the amount of decimals shown

Tags: r, decimal, survival-analysis

When I do any data analysis through R, I'm getting the return of whole numbers only. Is there any way to receive a more exact estimation such as 2 decimal places.

For example:

```
survfit(Surv(data$TTE, data$event) ~ 1, data = data)
```

returns

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(data$TTE, data$event) ~ 1, data = data)

       n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,] 116     92      7       5       9
```

Whereas the median in other processing software is actually 7.1 months (95%CI 4.9 - 9.3). Is there a way to get this to return in a more exact way using my code?

Comment: What you're seeing is just a printed summary. If you assign the output from `survfit` to a variable, then you can extract the values of all the different metrics including the median. See the linked answer for examples.

Comment: Hi @neilfws when I do as is suggested in the example I get the increased number of decimals but still think R is rounding. As my next output is 7.0 months (95%CI 5.0 - 9.0) in what I know should be an output of 7.1 months (95%CI 4.9 - 9.3)

Comment: Perhaps your "other processing software" calculates things differently? It would help to [make the question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data)`, if that is not too large, and to know what the other software was.